What is the definition of average SOC and cycle depth?

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/284655052_Degradation_Behaviour_of_Lithium-Ion_Batteries_based_on_Field_Measured_Frequency_Regulation_Mission_Profile
I was reading this paper which uses the terms average SOC and cycle depth. I am wondering exactly what they refer to as when I try searching their definitions I get things related to deep cycle batteries and such.
It would be helpful if an equation could be provided as well to get an idea of what they mean:
e.g. cycle depth = (max cycles - min cycles) or something similar
